# faces-config.xml keep updating itself

Tags: managed-bean, faces-config

I have 2 faces-config.xml file.

I created a new page and added bean into the second file.
However, the first faces-config file automatically keeps adding bean to it as well.

Thus, every time I tried to refresh a page there is a classNotFoundException because there are 2 classes
for that page.

Can anyone tell me the cause and how to fix this?
(I am using ibm rad6)